# Ошибка инициализации полей, при обращение к ним из inner класса

Tags: android, kotlin

В классе фрагменте есть поле

```
private lateinit var calendarsPresenter: CalendarsPresenter
```

в `onStart()` я его инициализирую

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    calendarsPresenter = CalendarsPresenterImpl()
    calendarsPresenter.onAttach(this)
}
```

В этом же классе есть вложенный класс

```
inner class ActionModeCallback : ActionMode.Callback {

        override fun onCreateActionMode(mode: ActionMode, menu: Menu): Boolean {
            mode.menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.selected_menu, menu)
            return true
        }

        override fun onPrepareActionMode(mode: ActionMode, menu: Menu): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onActionItemClicked(mode: ActionMode, item: MenuItem): Boolean {
            return when (item.itemId) {
                R.id.menu_remove -> {
                    calendarsPresenter.removeClicked(calendarAdapter.uuidRemoveList)
                    mode.finish()
                    true
                }

                else -> false
            }
        }

        override fun onDestroyActionMode(mode: ActionMode) {
            calendarsPresenter.actionModeDestroyed()
        }
    }
```

Так вот, когда я пытаюсь обратиться к полю `calendarsPresenter` из `inner` класса, то появляется ошибка

```
 kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property calendarsPresenter has not been initialized
 at com.likhanov.mainwork.ui.activities.main.CalendarsFragment.access$getCalendarsPresenter$p(CalendarsFragment.kt:26)
 at com.likhanov.mainwork.ui.activities.main.CalendarsFragment$ActionModeCallback.onDestroyActionMode(CalendarsFragment.kt:188)
```

Но почему это происходит, ведь я инициализировал поле?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте инициализировать в методе onCreatedView

Ниже протестил у себя(но с Активностью), может поможет вам. Все работает корректно.

```
class RegistrationActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


private lateinit var calendarsPresenter: SignInPresenter

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);
   calendarsPresenter = SignInPresenter(this);
    calendarsPresenter.onErrorCancel()



    ActionModeCallback().onDestroyActionMode()

}


inner class ActionModeCallback : ActionMode.Callback {
    override fun onDestroyActionMode(p0: ActionMode?) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    override fun onCreateActionMode(mode: ActionMode, menu: Menu): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    override fun onPrepareActionMode(mode: ActionMode, menu: Menu): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun onActionItemClicked(mode: ActionMode, item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.email_sign_in_button -> {
                calendarsPresenter.onErrorCancel()
                mode.finish()
                true
            }

            else -> false
        }
    }

     fun onDestroyActionMode() {
        calendarsPresenter.onErrorCancel()
    }
}}
```